# One change: load elements before images are loaded

Tags: javascript, image, onload

I have a script that loads elements after loading the images which are in. I want to first load the elements and than images. Can someone help me?

Script:

```
jQuery.ias({
    container : '#con',
    item: '.bo',
    pagination: '.pages',
    next: '.next',
    loader: '<img src="loader.gif">',
    onLoadItems: function(items) {
        // hide new items while they are loading
        var $newElems = $(items).show().css({ opacity: 0 });
        // ensure that images load before adding to masonry layout
        $newElems.imagesLoaded(function(){
            // show elems now they're ready
            $newElems.animate({ opacity: 1 });
            $('#con').masonry( 'appended', $newElems, true );
        });
        return true;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

add class to image you want to hide while it is loading:

**load the element on the body the load your images:**

<img src="image.jpg" class="preload" />

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery(".preload").hide();
  // use :   jQuery(".preload").css("opacity","0");  to preserve the image place!
  jQuery(".preload").load(function(){ 
      jQuery(this).show();
      // Or jQuery(this).css("opacity","1");
  })
});
```

Comment: This could flash your images while the page is being loaded, you're better off setting them to `display: none` from CSS and then just removing the `.preload` after they are loaded. Also to preserve space, you should use `visibility: hidden` Using opacity is a hack. Oooops, another problem is that if the images are already cached, the load event of the images will fire before jQuery's `ready` handler and by time you call `$('.preload').load` the event could have already fired

Comment: The point is that I dont need them to be hidden while loading etc. I just want to load elements first and than the images... because it takes time to load images so user have to wait to see the element... as you can see in code I provided there is something like: // hide new items while they are loading... // ensure that images load before adding to masonry layout... // show elems now they're ready